# PostgreSQL driven by SQLAlchemy - Release Savepoint Idle in Transaction

Tags: postgresql, transaction, connection-pooling, sqlalchemy, savepoint

While running PostgreSQL 13.12 (occurs in several versions of PG11/PG13) using SQLAlchemy 1.3, we are occasionally hitting issues where increased concurrency leaves certain transactions (and their nested transactions) in the "Idle in Transaction" state with the `RELEASE SAVEPOINT ...` query.

Looking at the currently running queries, it is not clear why transactions have stopped moving forward.  I have also observed this behavior without any hanging locks:

| pid | datname | duration | query | state | application_name | wait_event_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27662 | app | 22:22:37.429569 | `select pg_advisory_xact_lock(resource_id) from resource where uuid = '018afcac-a5ab-7a5c-9eb4-2d8b0be4b556'` | active | http.api.1 | Lock |
| 25830 | app | 22:22:29.236398 | `RELEASE SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_5` | idle in transaction | http.api.0 | Client |
| 21490 | app | 22:22:29.015862 | `select pg_advisory_xact_lock(resource_id) from resource where uuid = '018afcac-a5ab-7a5c-9eb4-2d8b0be4b556'` | active | http.api.0 | Lock |
| 27674 | app | 22:22:27.780581 | `RELEASE SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_3` | idle in transaction | http.api.2 | Client |
| 29120 | app | 22:22:26.053851 | `select pg_advisory_xact_lock(resource_id) from resource where uuid = '018afcac-a5ab-7a5c-9eb4-2d8b0be4b556'` | active | http.api.2 | Lock |

Any way to debug this?  This API call generally works, with the session being cleaned up and does not fail consistently.  We are using SQL Alchemy's connection pooling to manage the connections - closed sessions will return the connection to the pool and issue a rollback to clean up the connection (when commit should have committed all other statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sessions are in the state `idle in transaction` because you didn't run `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`, and `RELEASE SAVEPOINT` does not close a transaction (only a subransaction). The bug is in your application, which apparently forgot to close the transaction. The state `idle in transaction` does not mean that PostgreSQL is busy: it is waiting for the next statement from your application.

Comment: The strange thing is - all 3 Python web application processes (Tornado) still appear to be in the active transaction. Spying on the process they are all stopped within their respective functions close to the mentioned locks.  When checking the blocking locks, it looks like RELEASE SAVEPOINT is the blocking process. When simulating a single user, no connections are left in a idle in transaction state.

Wondering if SQL Alchemy or PostgreSQL is getting tripped up by nested transactions.

Comment: Yes, they are in an active transaction - because your program didn't close the transaction. This is unrelated to the savepoint.

Comment: Would the failure to commit/rollback be near the immediate statement that would follow RELEASE SAVEPOINT?  These are savepoints generated by the ORM, and I believe the outermost nested transaction would be SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_1 --- it looks like more lines of code should have executed within the transaction before commit.  Looking at the processes, I believe there are more active transactions then there are processes (5 active queries, 3 synchronous python processes - possibly 2 transactions that failed to close properly).

Comment: No, a savepoint is never the outermost transaction. Perhaps it is the fault of the ORM, perhaps it is your code, but it sure ain't the database.

Comment: Wanted to followup.  I finally was able to trace the transaction issues.  There were a few points where our nested transactions failed to rollback. One issue was that the savepoint wrapped function execution was accidentally moved out of its try: except: block in Python.  A second issue was that a database driver error (psycopg2) was bubbling up to SQL Alchemy.  We weren't catching this particular error and it blocked the savepoint rollback (could no longer issue queries for session/agent). Using a context manager helped release or rollback of a savepoint in Python / SQL Alchemy.

Comment: Your comments on idle in transaction meaning the database is waiting for the application to send its next query have been very helpful in understanding the issues that were occurring. I observed this too if the application was doing a lot of non-DB work within the transaction, or when waiting on a debug point.